# Is there a way to get a list of when each site in a web application was last accessed?

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-enterprise, powershell, site, web-analytics

I need to get a list of each site and determine the last time someone hit that site.  We're in the process of cleaning up our Sharepoint and this data would be very useful.  I see that `SPWeb` has a `LastItemModifiedDate` but nothing about the last time the site was accessed.

Is there any way to get this type of information?

Answer (score 0):

You should rely on Web Analytics Report.

From Site Actions -> Site Settings -> Site Web Analytics Reports

This report will give you Page View count etc. You can then use this values to determine if a site has 0 page view count and act up on those.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ecm/archive/2010/03/21/introducing-web-analytics-in-sharepoint-2010.aspx